# What does this error mean Set-Location "path" is null in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Total newbie here...

I am attempting to execute a ps1 file using Powershell and receiving an error.  What  does this error mean? I'm concerned that OneDrive is causing an issue with the path.

Running this ps1 file by opening powershell and entering:

```
PowerShell -executionpolicy Bypass -NoExit C:\Users\Terry\OneDrive\desktop\WindowsPull.ps1
```

This is the file:
    $segmentFolders = Get-ChildItem | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'}

Error:

```
 Set-Location : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null. Change the value of argument
"path" to a non-null value.
At C:\Users\Terry\OneDrive\desktop\WindowsPull.ps1:4 char:1
+ Set-Location $videoDir.FullName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: It means that the variable `$videoDir.Fullname` is `null`. Ensure that the expected path/string is actually provided for `Set-Location`. The `$videoDir` is empty probably because the `Get-ChildItem` function does not find the directories.

Comment: Perhaps change `where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory'}` to `where {$_.Attributes -match 'Directory'}` or `where {$_.PSIsContainer}`

Comment: Nailed it @MathiasR.Jessen!!!  Thanks for the direction.  `where {$_.Attributes -match 'Directory'}` worked!  Huge thanks!